# Is it better to use a "?" or a ";" in a URL?

Tags: uri, url-parameters, url-design

In my application, I redirect an HTTP request and also pass a parameter. Example:

```
http://localhost:9000/home;signup=error
```

Is it better to use a `;` or shall I use a `?` i.e. shall I do `http://localhost:9000/home;signup=error` or `http://localhost:9000/home?signup=error`?

Are the above two different from each other semantically?

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is a reserved character; I have read that this is both valid and invalid, but I have used it for 'slugs' when templating.

Should you choose to use it, percent-encode the query string using `%3F` which is not human readable, but will produce the `?`.  (An encoder is recommended)

Perhaps you will find a more suitable solution for your redirects by adding an `.htaccess` file to your project.